# Windows Authentication ot working with Web App IIS C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, iis-7.5

I have placed a c# web app on our IIS server, creating an application for it. I then changed the "Authentication" type to windows authentication for the site and also for the xml tags in my web config file. Now, when I navigate to the site, it asks me for the login username and password, but then does not authenticate, asking over and over for my credentials. In the browser login popup, i am typing
Domain\Username
Password.

How can I see why it will not authenticate, or find out what is wrong. I have done everything in articles I have found, but cannot find the issue. It is as if the server does not authenticate, but yet I can remote desktop to it with the same credentials, so it is on the domain.

Here is my web.conf file snippet with the settings:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
enable="true" />
```

I also added the same configuration to the application host file on the IIS server. The entry is below:

```
<location path="TaxFormerWebApp">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true">
                    <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />                                               
                    </providers>            
                </windowsAuthentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions applyToWebDAV="false" />
                <verbs applyToWebDAV="false" />
                <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false" />
            </requestFiltering>
```

Comment: can you show the code and where it's located in regards to how you are doing this.. if it's not authenticated then you need to redirect to the login page..but can't determine that without seeing existing code remote access in and IIS_USER are 2 different things btw.. who's  your system admin..?

Comment: I understand they are different things, but thought maybe it couldn't get the user information from the domain. I will post some code.